# How to fix Unexpected token error, expected “}”

Tags: reactjs, text

**I keep on getting an error saying unexpected token but have no idea where that unexpected token is at? Please help**

**Code is below**

```
import React from 'react';
import react, { Component } from 'react'
import { Plateform, StyleSheet, View,Text } from 'react-native';



function Header() {
  return (
    <div>
    <this.View style={style}/>
    <Text style={[styles.setFontSize.setColorRed]}>Welcome to the dealership!</Text>
      <header className="header">
        <div className="col1">
        </div>
        <div className="col2">
        <div className="menu">
        <h3>About</h3>
        <h3>Cars</h3>
        <h3>Contact</h3>
        <h3>Search</h3>
        <header/>
        <View/>
      </div>
      </div>





**Here is where the error seems to be happing**

  );
}
export default Header;

App = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  setFontSize: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight : 'bold'
  },
  setColorRed : {
    color: '#f44336'
  }
});
```

**Error is below as well**

> Line 37:12:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"
>
> 35 |    36 | App = StyleSheet.create({
>
> > 37 |   container: {
> >          |            ^   38 |     flex: 1,   39 |     justifyContent: 'center',   40 |     alignItems: 'center'

Comment: Easy to understand, you must miss a right bracket, or other syntax error.

Comment: But in where at tho @YangHG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've incorrectly closed `Header`, i.e. `<Header/>` versus `</Header>`, and you dropped two closing div tags outside the header instead of in it, and the first div is missing its closing tag. I assume you don't want your view in the header, so I left it below it.

This is where using proper indentations and any decent IDE would help catch/identify these for you.

```
function Header() {
  return (
    <div>
      <this.View style={style}/>
      <Text style={[styles.setFontSize.setColorRed]}>Welcome to the dealership!</Text>
      <header className="header">
        <div className="col1"></div>
        <div className="col2">
          <div className="menu">
            <h3>About</h3>
            <h3>Cars</h3>
            <h3>Contact</h3>
            <h3>Search</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <View/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose `header` HTML element and then wrap the component with `<div>`

```
function Header() {
  return (
    <div>
      <this.View style={style} />
      <Text style={[styles.setFontSize.setColorRed]}>
        Welcome to the dealership!
      </Text>
      <header className="header">
        <div className="col1"></div>
        <div className="col2">
          <div className="menu">
            <h3>About</h3>
            <h3>Cars</h3>
            <h3>Contact</h3>
            <h3>Search</h3>
            <header />
            <View />
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  )
}
```

There are some really useful editor extensions can add and rename close tag for you, like `Auto Close Tag` and `Auto Rename Tag`.